# Vimtex - How to run :VimtexCompile on start using lua

Tags: neovim, plugin-vimtex, vimscript-lua

How do I execute `:VimtexCompile` automatically whenever I open a `.tex` file? As mentioned in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/234#issuecomment-398071943), this is done in Vimscript via:

```
augroup vimtex_config
  autocmd User VimtexEventInitPost VimtexCompile
augroup END
```

I've tried a bunch of variations of the following:

```
-- Example 1
local VimtexGroup = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("VimtexGroup", { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "User" }, {
  pattern = "VimtexEventInitPost",
  group = VimtexGroup,
  command = ":VimtexCompile",
})

-- Example 2
local VimtexGroup = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("VimtexGroup", { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "User" }, {
  pattern = "VimtexEventInitPost",
  group = VimtexGroup,
  callback = function()
    [[VimtexEventInitPre VimtexCompile]]
  end,
})
```

Honestly, the lua version of vimscript really confuses me, so I'm just guessing here.

Of course, I can just map something like `<leader>c` to `":VimtexCompile<CR>`, but I'm specifically trying to do this with `autocmd` to better understand the lua version.

Thanks

Comment: VimTeX already has a lot of default mappings, e.g. `\ll` to start compilation. Thus, you don't need to make mappings yourself unless you want to remap. You should probably read the docs. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```lua
local augroup = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("VimtexGroup", { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("User", {
  pattern = "VimtexEventInitPost",
  group = augroup,
  command = "VimtexCompile",
})
```

Notice you don't need the `:` here. The command is executed as a Vim command, which is what you type when you do `:...`.

If this *doesn't* work, then you should open an issue on GitHub because it is likely a bug or that something is misconfigured on your end.

Comment: I think it's bugged because your snippet still isn't working for me.  For context, I've been testing these in `nvim/after/ftplugin/tex.lua`. What's weird is it works when *either* (i) I change `"VimtexEventInitPost"` to `"VimtexEventQuit"`, *or* (ii) I move the command to where I store all my other autocommands, e.g., `lua/config/autocmds.lua`. This is complicated by building off of the starter files from [LazyVim](https://github.com/LazyVim/LazyVim), so there may be some side effects there. I'll file an issue if I don't see a similar one there already. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, no. If you put this under `after/ftplugin/tex.lua` you are creating the autocommand _after_ the event `VimtexEventInitPost` is fired. You need to create the autocommand earlier, preferably during the sourcing of `init.lua` (either explicitly or implicitly from some file that is sourced by it).

Comment: Notice that VimTeX does _not_ need any lazy loading! In fact, if you force lazy loading of VimTeX, you risk breaking expected behaviour. So make sure to _not_ lazy load anything.

Comment: Your explanations really helped me understand how these config pieces are interacting. Thanks!

Comment: No problem; glad to hear it was helpful!

Answer (score -1):

The following ended up working for me. The issue was that I needed to also execute `VimtexView`.

```
local vimtex = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("vimtex", { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("User", {
  pattern = "VimtexEventInitPost",
  command = ":VimtexCompile",
  group = vimtex,
})
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("User", {
  pattern = "VimtexEventInitPost",
  command = ":VimtexView",
  group = vimtex,
})
```

Comment: I downvoted this, because it is _not_ true that you need to also execute `:VimtexView`. If you do, then what you want is not what you've asked for in your question.